# Can Microsoft's Service Broker be used for a producer-consumer scenario?

Tags: c#, sql-server, producer-consumer, service-broker

Using SQL Server 2008, ASP.NET, C#/VB/.NET

I have experience using SQL Server, but just starting with Service Broker.  I've been looking at Service Broker to help me with the following scenario:

- Customers come to our website and submit a request.
- This request is sent to a Partner's web service for handling and we get back a request Id (GUID) which both of us can use in tracking the request.
- We save info about the request in a Tracking table and wait for status updates from our Partner.
- Over the next hours/days/weeks, our Partner sends us status updates on the request via a webhook listener we have running on our end.
- For performance reasons, it was recommended this webhook just validate the update and queue it on a "processing queue" for later processing.
- We have a processing application which retrieves the status updates from the processing queue and handles the update -- mostly updating the Tracking table and sometimes by requesting files from the Partner. Requesting files may take some time, hence having this processing separate from the webhook receiving the updates. And there is a good possibility we may need several instances of the processing application.

Since we are already using SQL Server, I was hoping to leverage Service Broker to provide the processing queue.  Some of the issues I'm struggling with are:

- I think we only need 1 processing queue. Most of the SB documentation shows an Initiator and a Target queue.
- When the processing app receives an update, I'd like to continue to process more updates for that specific request (conversation groups?). Examples I've seen show receiving a message, sending a response, and then closing the conversation. I'd like to keep the conversation open until we receive a "request complete" update from our Partner.
- After receiving an update from the queue, do I need to send a response message? If so, to who? It looks like my Consumer app now has to be also a Producer.
- I've read all the warnings about "conversation leaks" and "fire-and-forget" anti-patterns, so I want to follow best practices.

Are there any good examples of using Service Broker for a producer-consumer scenario like this?

If you have any questions or need more information, please let me know.  Thanks!

randy

Comment: Who said _"fire-and-forget"_ is an _"anti-pattern"_?  Not every message sent requires a response.  The Producer (fire-and-forget) in a [producer-consumer](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/PublishSubscribeChannel.html) pattern generally doesn't care about responses (also a bit hard in the multiple subscriber scenario) whilst [request-reply](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/RequestReply.html) does.  Recommend you check out [this](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/) site and the book mentioned there

Comment: It's an antipattern with sevice broker, because it can leave conversation endpoints hanging. See [here](https://rusanu.com/2006/04/06/fire-and-forget-good-for-the-military-but-not-for-service-broker-conversations/)

Comment: You certainly can use service broker for this, but you may prefer to just use a table. For the implementation (and the reason why), see [this post](https://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) by our friendly neightbourhood Service Broker guru, Remus Rusanu.

Comment: Right after I posted this, I thought maybe I'd better look for Plan B -- using a table as a queue.  I've seen it done before, but was looking for something a little less home grown.  Anyway, I saw several of Remus Rusanu's articles.  Great stuff!  Learned a lot!

Comment: I would argue that for a reliable, persistent producer-consumer you really need a queue. Service Broker is a fully fledged *messaging* infrastructure, that just happens to use queues as inboxes. See https://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/ for my musings on how to use tables as queues in SQL Server. These days though I would opt for an PaaS, like Azure Service Bus, or use something like one of the many message buses in Redis (https://redis.io/topics/pubsub, https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro)

Comment: @RemusRusanu  Thanks for the reply!  Yes -- I need a queue.  And yes I agree totally that SB is a messaging service that uses queues for storage (unfortunate choice of names as you've mentioned).  But I'm puzzled that you would recommend other messaging services for my scenario instead of a queue implementation.  Would you please elaborate a little? Also -- we are trying to keep this project under budget.  Paying for an online queuing service (Azure, Amazon, Google) where we cannot accurately predict billing costs has the bosses worried a lot.  That's why SB seemed like a "cheap" solution.

Comment: If your requirements are fit within a table in a SQL instance, go for it. But if the solution is wildly successful and  you'll get traffic/load/utilization galore, you'll want to move to a service operated by somebody else that solves the scale/troubleshooting/perf for you

Comment: As for Redis: latency and throughput vs. reliability. If you don't need persistent, durable and ACID semantics, then Redis is going to run circles around your SQL.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies -- greatly appreciated!  Due to time and resource (just me) constraints, I'm going with "table as queue".  We will not need blazing speed -- right now, I'm estimating about 2-3 enqueues per minute for worse case.  And dequeuing and processing isn't time critical.  I did stress test my queuing stored procedures (via SqlQueryStress) and so far, so good.  All that being said, I got a lot of useful information and hopefully next time I'll be able to put the other suggestions to good use.  Thanks again!

Comment: One other consideration:  I won't be consulting for this company forever, so I need to leave them with a solution the next guy (in all likelihood, a Microsoft guy like me) understands.  Therefore, I rarely stray far afield from MS solutions.  Yes -- I do remember the time when the phrase was "Nobody gets fired for buying IBM". Haha!